# Filtering Order Reports in Magento to show which brand's products were sold

Tags: magento, report

We are creating a flash sale site and need to be able to filter our Order Reports by brand and export this data so that we can quickly and accurately create Purchase Orders for them after the sale has been run. Right now, we are only able to filter orders by period and order status etc, but we cannot see without clicking on each order what was purchased and from what brand.

Can anyone help us here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try the following links :

- [Creating custom report](http://codemagento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/)
- [Custom Reports in Magento](http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento)
- [Create custom reports in Magento Admin](http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/)